# Is there an installer to automate the installation of 2 independant programes in windows?

Tags: installation, automation

The purpose is just to avoid user interaction.

The programes I want to automate are **Adobe AIR** and **Flash media live encoder**

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the applications being installed, some installers just don't support silent installs or even actively prohibits them.

If silent installs is possible you can use most installer makers. This seems like a good resource on [sourceforge](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/index.php).

> This is a system for fully automating the installation of Windows 2000 Professional and Server, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003.
>
> Features include:

```
* Automated install of operating system, hotfixes and applications.
* Full documentation and source code.
* Support for floppy, CD-ROM, and "nothing but net" installs.
* True unattended installation, not disk imaging.
* No Windows servers required; use your Unix servers instead.
* No Unix servers required; use your Windows servers after all.
* Completely free.
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want the redistributable version of the Adobe AIR installer (this version is optimised to allow silent/unattended installs, and doesn't include any bundled bloatware or toolbars). Get it from http://www.adobe.com/products/air/runtime_distribution1.html

Answer (score 1):

You could install [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) `@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin` and subsequently install Adobe Air and FlashPlayer using respectively `cinst AdobeAIR` and `cinst flashplayeractivex`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.almeza.com/

The FAQ doesn't show Windows 7 but Vista is there so I think it can be run on W7, too.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your application, check if it supports unattended installation or silent installation, then you may use suitable command line parameters to install.

also you can use Auto-it to make an auto installer script for most of the applications and it's quite easy and suited.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a built-in installer creator that can bundle multiple executables located at `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\iexpress.exe`

For silent installs - as others mentioned - you would need to ensure that you package silent versions of the programs you are planning to deploy.